# catch programmatically triggered event with jquery

Tags: jquery, events, eventtrigger

I have an input element which has a keypress event handler attached:

```
// ASSIGN ENTER KEYPRESS TO PAGE SELECTOR
$(document).on('keypress', '.list-ui-page-selector', turnPage);
```

The user enters a number into the input and presses the ENTER key. The turnPage() function checks what the pressed key was. If it was ENTER, then starts an ajax request:

```
function turnPage(event){
    if(event.which != 13) return;
    var page = $(this).val();
    var unique = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d.]/g,'');
    animateTableUpdating(unique);
    ajaxRequest(unique, null, null, page);
}// turnPage
```

This works properly, but I'd like some buttons which can increment and decrement the number value in the input field. When I increased or decreased the value I trigger an ENTER keypress event:

```
// PAGE SCROLLING BUTTONS
$(document).on('click', ".list-ui-next-page", function(){
    var unique = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d{8}/gi);
    var page = parseInt($("#list-ui-page-selector\\["+unique+"\\]").val());  
    var page_total = parseInt($("#list-ui-page-total\\["+unique+"\\]").val());  
    if(page < page_total){
        page++;  
        $("#list-ui-page-selector\\["+unique+"\\]").val(page);
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 13;
        e.keyCode = 13;
        $("#list-ui-page-selector\\["+unique+"\\]").trigger(e);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the programically triggered event is not handled by $(document).on('keypress', '.list-ui-page-selector', turnPage); and turnPage is not invoked. How could I catch these events too?

Comment: maybe you should trigger the event on the document and add a e.target = element instead. tried that out?

Comment: You're triggering a `keydown` event but handling a `keypress` event.